# How to achieve this effect using gl-react-native?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am trying to apply an effect to an background image (seen left) to create the effect you see on the right.

[image]

I have tried using [LinearGradient](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-linear-gradient) and stacked each layer with it, e.g.

```
return (
  <View>
    <Image style={styles.container} source={require('../../assets/slides/pioneer-party.jpg')} />
    <LinearGradient
        start={{x: 0.0, y: 0.0}} end={{x: 1.0, y: 1.0}}
        locations={[0,0.25,0.5,0.75,1]}
        colors={['#692eff', '#642cf4', '#602ae9', '#5224c8', '#5e29e5']}
        style={styles.contentContainer}
      >
      <LinearGradient
        colors={['rgba(13,105,255,0)', '#0069ff']}
        style={styles.contentContainer2}
      >
      </LinearGradient>
    </LinearGradient>
  </View>
)
```

It didn't achieve the effect I wanted. I then had a look at gl-react-color-blending. I couldn't get the blendMode to work with LinearGradient. I opened an [issue](https://github.com/miklosme/gl-react-color-blending/issues/6) with the author, but he also didn't know how to do it, but believed it can be done using gl-react.

I have asked on ReactiFlux, but no-one seems to know how to do it.

I am not sure how to stack the layers/components so that they can achieve this visual effect.

Does anyone have experience with Gl React and can possibly point me in the right direction?

Thanks.

UPDATE:

Thanks for the suggestion. I have updated the code: (feel free to remove the wrapping LinearGradient)

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
  Platform,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View,
  TouchableOpacity,
  Dimensions,
  Image,
  FlatList,
  AsyncStorage,
  TextInput,
  ActivityIndicator,
  ScrollView,
  ImageBackground
} from 'react-native';
import ImageGradient from 'react-native-image-gradient';
import LinearGradient from 'react-native-linear-gradient';
import metrics from '../../utils/metrics'

export default class Example extends Component {

  render() {
    return (
      <LinearGradient
        colors={['rgba(13,105,255,0)', '#0069ff']}
        style={styles.gradient}
      >
        <ImageGradient 
          mainStyle={styles.container}
          gradientStyle={styles.gradient}
          localImage={false}
          imageUrl={'http://uppercase.army/pioneer-party.jpg'}
          startPosition={{x:0,y:0}}
          endPosition={{x:0,y:0.5}}
          rgbcsvEnd={'163,73,255'}
          rgbcsvStart={'6,0,205'}
          opacityStart={0.8}
          opacityEnd={0.7}
        >
        </ImageGradient>
      </LinearGradient>
    );
  }

}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({

 container: {
    width: metrics.DEVICE_WIDTH,
    height: metrics.DEVICE_HEIGHT,
    resizeMode: 'cover', // or 'stretch'
  },
  gradient: {
    width: metrics.DEVICE_WIDTH,
    height: metrics.DEVICE_HEIGHT,
  },
});
```

It comes very close to the effect I am after:

[image]

Do you think it's possible to apply a blend mode of softlight to the image using https://github.com/miklosme/gl-react-color-blending ? As ultimately that's what my designer is after.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you try this

```
/**
 * Sample React Native App
 * https://github.com/facebook/react-native
 * @flow
 */

import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
  Platform,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View,
  TouchableOpacity,
  Dimensions,
  Image,
  FlatList,
  AsyncStorage,
  TextInput,
  ActivityIndicator,
  ScrollView,
  ImageBackground
} from 'react-native';
import { ListItem, Left, Body, Right, Title } from "native-base";
import ImageGradient from 'react-native-image-gradient';
import LinearGradient from 'react-native-linear-gradient';


const window = Dimensions.get('window');

const instructions = Platform.select({
  ios: 'Press Cmd+R to reload,\n' +
    'Cmd+D or shake for dev menu',
  android: 'Double tap R on your keyboard to reload,\n' +
    'Shake or press menu button for dev menu',
});





  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
         <ImageGradient 
            mainStyle={styles.YOURS}
            gradientStyle={styles.YOURS}
            localImage={false}
            imageUrl={'http://auraypantin.fr/wp-content/uploads/2013/12/PICT0534.jpg'}
            startPosition ={{x:0,y:0}}
            rgbcsvStart={'255,255,255'}
            rgbcsvEnd={'0,0,0'}
            opacityStart={0.9}
            opacityEnd={0.0}
        >
        </ImageGradient>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({

 container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    backgroundColor: '#F5FCFF',
  },
  gradient: {
    width: 200,
    height: 200,
  },
});
```

Comment: By changing the opacity also was able to match it. 
Check the screenshot:  https://ibb.co/ejrm2o

Comment: Ok. So you suggest changing the opacity of the image, and then possibly that will change the gradient over it to be closer to the design. I will give it a try thanks.

Comment: Hope so, let me know if it worked or will try some other approach.
Thanks

Comment: Hi @Pramod - I am going to mark your answer as correct. Although my designer is adamant on using blendmodes, which I have not been able to do using RN. (funny enough Flutter supports it out of the box.